# Pegar código fonte da página com extensão do Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensão

É possível criar uma extensão para o Chrome que pegue ou o código fonte da página ou o texto todo (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>), para enviar isso para um site externo (para mineração de dados) e que devolva o conteúdo resultante do site? (no caso, um grafo com os termos principais).

obs: form que criei:
(está em popup.js)

```
    var my_form=document.createElement('FORM');
    my_form.name='entrada';
    my_form.method='POST';
    my_form.action='http://sobek.ufrgs.br/newSobekSite/new-sobek.php';  
    my_form.submit();
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54236/discussion-on-question-by-luciano-zancan-pegar-codigo-fonte-da-pagina-com-extens)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Conforme está reposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11696154/1518921) é possível:

**manifest.json**

> **Nota:** Troque `<all_urls>` por algo como `"*:*//site1.com", "*://*site2.com"`, estes sites seriam os que necessitam você deve "liberar acesso" para pode fazer a comunicação.
>
> **Nota:** É provável que você deva adicionar a permissão `clipboardRead` (e talvez a `clipboardWrite`) no manifest:

```
{
    "name": "Get pages source",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Pega o conteudo da página e envia para um servidor",
    "browser_action": {
       "default_icon": "icon.png",
       "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "tabs",
        "clipboardWrite",
        "clipboardRead",
        "<all_urls>"
    ]
}
```

**popup.js**

Você poderá usar Ajax para enviar para outro servidor o `request.source`, como no exemplo:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
    if (request.action === "getSource") {
        var message, data, xhr;

        message = document.querySelector("#message");
        data = request.source;

        message.innerText = "Enviando ao servidor...";

        xhr  = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "http://site1/webservice.php", true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    message.innerText = "Resposta do servidor: " + xhr.responseText;
                } else {
                    message.innerText = "Err: " + xhr.status;
                }
            }
        };

        //Enviando dados como RAW
        xhr.send(request.source);
    }
});

function onWindowLoad()
{
    var message = document.querySelector('#message');

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: "getPagesSource.js"
    }, function() {
        // If you try and inject into an extensions page or the webstore/NTP you'll get an error
        if (chrome.extension.lastError) {
            message.innerHTML = "Erro ao executar o script : <br>" + chrome.extension.lastError.message;
        }
    });
}

window.onload = onWindowLoad;
```

**getPagesSource.js**

Para copiar como se fosse o usuário copiando utilizamos `window.getSelection().addRange` e um `<div contentEditable="true"></div>`

```
function copyFromDOM(target, rich) {
    var range, dom, source, posX, posY;

    posX = window.pageXOffset;
    posY = window.pageYOffset;

    dom = document.createElement("div");
    dom.contentEditable = true;

    range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(target);

    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("copy");

    document.body.appendChild(dom);

    dom.focus();

    document.execCommand("paste");

    source = rich === true ? dom.innerHTML : dom.textContent;

    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    document.body.removeChild(dom);

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        window.scrollTo(posX, posY);
    }, 1);

    range = dom = null;
    return source;
}

chrome.extension.sendMessage({
    action: "getSource",
    source: copyFromDOM(document.body, false)//Copia apenas texto
});
```

> **Nota:** Se quiser copiar com "rich-text", então use `copyFromDOM(document.body, true)`
>
> **Nota:** Houve um problema no uso por parte do OP quanto a função `copyFromDOM(document.body, false)`, ele estava a usar o *GoogleChrome 38*, mas após o update para versão mais recente a função passou a funcionar normalmente.

### Copiando código-fonte da página

Para copiar o código fonte da página altere o `getPagesSource.js` para algo como (baseado na resposta do usuário [Rob W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w)):

**getPagesSource.js**

```
// @author Rob W <https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w>
// Demo: var serialized_html = DOMtoString(document);

function DOMtoString(document_root) {
    var html = '',
        node = document_root.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        switch (node.nodeType) {
        case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
            html += node.outerHTML;
            break;
        case Node.TEXT_NODE:
            html += node.nodeValue;
            break;
        case Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE:
            html += '<![CDATA[' + node.nodeValue + ']]>';
            break;
        case Node.COMMENT_NODE:
            html += '<!--' + node.nodeValue + '-->';
            break;
        case Node.DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE:
            // (X)HTML documents are identified by public identifiers
            html += "<!DOCTYPE " + node.name + (node.publicId ? ' PUBLIC "' + node.publicId + '"' : '') + (!node.publicId && node.systemId ? ' SYSTEM' : '') + (node.systemId ? ' "' + node.systemId + '"' : '') + '>\n';
            break;
        }
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
    return html;
}

chrome.extension.sendMessage({
    action: "getSource",
    source: DOMtoString(document)
});
```

### Servidor que recebe os dados

Como não sei qual a linguagem do seu servidor, irei fornecer um exemplo com PHP, este exemplo apenas grava em um arquivo, mas você pode alterar para um banco de dados e utiliza dados `RAW` ao invés de `x-www-form-urlencoded` (tipo formulários HTML), *isto é apenas um exemplo*, você pode enviar os dados de outras maneiras para o servidor:

**webservice.php**

```
<?php
if (false === ($input = fopen('php://input', 'r'))) {
    echo 'Erro ao ler os dados recebidos';
} else if (false === ($output = fopen('meu-arquivo.txt', 'w'))) {
    echo 'Erro abrir arquivo para gravação';
    fclose($input);
    $input = NULL;
} else {
    $hasData = false;

    while (false === feof($input)) {
        $data = fgets($input, 128);
        if ($data !== '') {
            $hasData = true;
        }

        fwrite($output, $data);
    }

    fclose($input);
    fclose($output);

    $input = $output = NULL;

    echo $hasData ? 'Ok' : 'Área de seleção vazia, tente novamente';
}
```

Se for enviar via POST com `x-www-form-urlencoded` (tipo formulários HTML) será necessário usar `setRequestHeader` e `window.encodeURIComponent`:

```
        xhr  = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "http://site1/webservice.php", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    message.innerText = "Resposta do servidor: " + xhr.responseText;
                } else {
                    message.innerText = "Err: " + xhr.status;
                }
            }
        };

        //Troque isto pela sua variável que é usada no SERVIDOR
        xhr.send('minha_variavel_do_servidor=' + window.encodeURIComponent(request.source));
```

> **Note:** `window.encodeURIComponent` trabalha com UTF-8 talvez seja necessário no servidor decodificar estes dados, acaso você use `windows-1252` ou `iso-8859-1`

### Mostrando resultado em um pop-up ou nova janela

Apenas de não estar no escopo da pergunta o AP solicitou o uso de pop-up para exibir os resultados, como muitas extensões usam pop-up para mostrar updates ou coisas semelhantes então resolvi fornecer tal exemplo. Para usar é necessário `window.open` e `window.open().document.write`, para usar na extensão chame dentro do Ajax:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var win;

    if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            //Abre uma nova aba ou pop-up
            win = window.open("", "_blank", "width=600, height=600");
            win.document.write(xhr.responseText);
        } else {
            //Mostra o resultado na extensão
            message.innerText = "Err: " + xhr.status;
        }
    }
};
```

### Evitando apagar o área de transferência do usuário

Se você quer somente copiar "textos" e evitar usar o `clipBoard` você pode usar o [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), ele irá copiar somente o texto e como eu disse não afetará a área de transferencia, assim também não será necessário adicionar permissões ao manifest, já que não iremos mais manipular o `clipBoard`, altere a função `copyFromDOM` para:

```
function copyFromDOM(target, rich) {
    return rich === true ? target.innerHTML : target.textContent;
}
```

Comment: Entendi! Nesse caso é $_POST['entrada'], como falei (pelo que vi no script). valeu! Mas para dar submit na página, será que só mandando send para o server já dá? Vou tentar hoje de noite/madrugada fazer isso. Valeu por toda a ajuda! obs: o fim do código termina em se post da entrada não for nulo, roda o post. Portanto acho que sim! E a resposta devo conseguir com um simples xhr.responseText ou algo assim, certo? obs2: Sim, não tenho conhecimento, sou novo nisso. Valeu por toda a ajuda aí! ;)

Comment: Oi! Uma dúvida, para fazer essa mesma extensão para o firefox eu vi que é necessário fazer alguns ajustes. Porém tem incompatibilidades como a permissão de clipboardread/write. Você saberia me responder o que é necessário modificar para tornar essa extensão disponível no Firefox também?

Comment: Firefox é algo que muda em muitos quesitos, como configuração do manifest, segue alguns exemplos: https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples, pra criar um extensão precisa do Firefox 45+ e então siga os passos aqui descritos: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension não sei se é incompatibilidade com clipboard, acho que talvez você tenha feito algo errado, porque nos exemplos que passei tem o pra copiar clipboard e o pra copiar DOM, se ambos falharam é porque não é problema de compatibilidade e sim algum erro. @LucianoZancan