# Como pego o que está copiado na área de transferência e coloco em uma variável?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extensão, área-de-transferência

Seria assim: ao copiar qualquer coisa usando <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, preciso colocar esse conteúdo em uma variável usando JavaScript. Não achei na internet como fazer isso. Alguém ajuda? 
Detalhe: É por meio de extensão. Seria para eu gravar o que está na área de transferência em uma variável para eu poder executar um processo já feito, em que ele copia o que está na página e envia por post, e após isso eu quero poder pegar o conteúdo que tinha guardado na variável e colocar devolta na área de transferência (para a extensão não influenciar nisso, pois pode ter problema se o usuário perder o que estava copiado na área de transferência

Comment: Você quer fazer isso em resposta a uma ação de "colar" do usuário, ou simplesmente fazer? Não tenho certeza, mas acho que os *browers* não permitiriam isso, por razões de segurança (imagina se qualquer site aberto no *browser* pudesse ir lendo o que está na área de transferência e enviando tudo pra um servidor qualquer, quanta informação privada que poderia vazar). [Fonte](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Granting_JavaScript_access_to_the_clipboard)

Comment: Acho que interpretei mal a pergunta, o comando de copiar ocorreu no próprio *browser* certo? Achei que você tinha copiado de algum lugar e queria "auto-colar" no *browser*...

Comment: Oi. Isso é para uma extensão. Ao copiar qualquer coisa em qualquer lugar, queria guardar numa variável antes de executar o script da extensão. Isso ser iria para nao perder o que esta copiado pelo usuário, pois a extensao trabalha copiando e enviado por post e no caso o que estava copiado antes seria perdido. Espero que de para entender agora, senão atualizo a pergunta

Comment: É bom mencionar esse tipo de coisa na pergunta, sim, já que influencia as respostas (numa página normal, como falei, não pode por razões de segurança; numa extensão, *provavelmente* pode, mas não tenho conhecimento para dizer com certeza).

Comment: Beleza! Estou no celular saindo pra aula agora mas meio dia eu atualizo a pergunta

Comment: pronto! Editei a pergunta

Answer (score 8):

Ao pressionar <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> no browser, você vai copiar o que estiver selecionado para a área de transferência. Logo antes dessa cópia ocorrer, é disparado o evento `copy`, que você pode interceptar. Lá dentro, verifique o valor da seleção, que é o que estará prestes a ser copiado:

```js
document.oncopy = function(e) {
    alert('prestes a copiar: ' + window.getSelection().toString());
}
```

```html
<p>selecione algo aqui e copie</p>
```

Comment: O cara já perguntou isto umas "10 vezes": http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50083/3635

Comment: mas não consegui fazer o tal "backup" ainda, e isso não tem lá nessa pergunta

Comment: tentei fazer isso mas dá problema, ele não executa mais o comando de selecionar o conteúdo da página após o 'paste'

Comment: @LucianoZancan Monte um [exemplo onde possamos ver o problema acontecendo](/help/mcve), e inclua na pergunta. Mas a essa altura você já deve saber que os browsers são propositadamente limitados em relação à área de transferência, por questões de segurança. Certas coisas não podem ser feitas. Um backup de qualquer coisa que esteja lá (por exemplo, um conjunto de células do Excel), não dá.

Comment: sim, eu sei! Por isso estou tendo tanta dificuldade em fazer isso.

Comment: @LucianoZancan depois que você editou a pergunta ela mudou quase totalmente de contexto, fazendo o que eu disse parecer que eu estava confuso ou não prestei atenção, isto para mim é uma pergunta camaleão, mas ok vamos a questão... Você quer salvar o clipboard em uma variável é só? Como eu disse na outra pergunta ao copiar o clipboard você vai copiar mais do que texto, vai copiar a formatação também, você quer realmente o clipboard ou você quer forçar copiar alguma coisa da página?

Comment: O Guilherme tem razão, a pergunta mudou tanto que invalidou a minha resposta e a marcação como duplicata. Reverti ao estado anterior. @LucianoZancan Se o objetivo final é aquele mesmo (mandar o conteúdo para análise em outro site), esclareça suas dúvidas na outra pergunta. As respostas lá não te ajudaram?

Comment: Oi guilherme e bfavaretto, me desculpem, acabo confundindo mesmo. Sou novato, enfim. Guilherme, eu queria poder salvar o que esta no clipboard antes de executar aquele script da extensao e depois do script retornar o conteudo salvo ao clipboard apenas para fins de nao perder o que estava no clipboard antes da extensao ser executada. Sera possivel fazer isso?

Comment: Seria um adicional a outra pergunta, apenas para nao perder o que estava copiado, pois o usuario poderia ter algo importante na clipboard e ao executar a extensao aquilo seria perdido

Comment: @LucianoZancan É que eu acho que você devia deixar a área de transferência pra lá, e dar outro jeito de mandar o conteúdo para o site remoto.

Comment: hmm. Tens alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Editei a resposta da outra pergunta, no final tem um exemplo usando `textContent`, note que ele irá só copiar os textos, a formatação não irá junto, mas me parece que é exatamente isto que você quer.

Comment: Eu acho que é isso mesmo @GuilhermeNascimento, a sua resposta já até continha todo o necessário pra não precisar do clipboard. Na verdade, tanto esta pergunta como aquela sofrem do [problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%C3%A9-o-problema-xy).

Comment: @bfavaretto Acho que eu cai nessa armadilha, o problema é que eu acho que cai para tentar evitar que o AP duplicasse a pergunta (ele já havia duplicado umas 2 vezes antes dessa), o problema é que ele não conseguia (consegue) transmitir a situação de uso e ou problemas decorrentes deste uso :(