# Post(XMLHttpRequest) javascript não funciona

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensão

pessoal estou desenvolvendo uma extensão para Chrome, mas a parte de post não está funcionando. A informação não chega. será que o problema é a extensão.

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
if (request.action === "getSource") {
    var message, data, xhr;

    message = document.querySelector("#message");
    data = request.source;

    message.innerText = "Enviando ao servidor...";

    var postUrl = 'webservice.php';

    xhr  = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', postUrl, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                message.innerText = "Resposta do servidor: " + xhr.responseText;
            } else {
                message.innerText = "Err: " + xhr.status;
            }
        }
      };

    //Enviando dados como RAW
    xhr.send(request.source);
     }
   });


function onWindowLoad() {

 var message = document.querySelector('#message');

 chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
 file: "getPagesSource.js"
 }, function() {

    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    message.innerText = 'There was an error injecting script : \n' +   chrome.runtime.lastError.message;
   }
   });

    }

    window.onload = onWindowLoad;
```

**webservice.php**

```
<?php

 $rt = $_POST['data'];
 $fp = fopen("bloco1.txt", "a");


 $escreve = fwrite($fp, '$rt');

 // Fecha o arquivo
 fclose($fp);

 ?>
```

Comment: Boa tarde sam, eu não recebo a informação na pagina php... é como se a informação não estivesse chegado.

Comment: eu estou tentando fazer isso. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50083/pegar-c%C3%B3digo-fonte-da-p%C3%A1gina-com-extens%C3%A3o-do-google-chrome

Comment: o sistema pega o código fonte inteiro da pagina e envia em forma de post para pagina php.

Comment: abaixo de" xhr.open('POST', postUrl, true);" ?

Comment: Não foi..... :(

Comment: Faz um teste simples. Troque o send por: `xhr.send("data=teste");`... agora pelo que vejo, o PHP não está retornando nada.

Comment: infelizmente está do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Eu acho que o problema é a extensão, ela não compila php. se o post chegar ele é escrito em um arquivo txt. mas não vai.

Comment: Eu vi que a intenção é escrever num arquivo, mas acho que seria melhor se certificar por meio de um echo se o "data" está chegando. Vai que o problema é na função de escrever o arquivo e vc está preso achando que o "data" não está chegando.

Comment: A extensão mostra o php como texto(o código fonte inteiro). então não mostra o echo.

Comment: Então qual a utilidade desse código: `xhr.responseText`? O responseText é o retorno do PHP, mas o PHP ao meu ver não retorna nada, não tem um echo ou outro código de resposta.

Comment: sam, olha o código inteiro aqui. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/328330/problema-com-extens%c3%a3o-para-o-google-chrome eu só mudei o webservice php